# GTX Titan Z BIG problem, barely hashing anything at all!

Tags: hashrate

so I just got a GTX Titan Z card as I read it should be able to run about mine ETH at about 50Mh/s since it has dual GPUs.  However, I just installed it and started up CGminer and was super shocked to see that each GPU is barley even running at 2MH/s.  I have current Windows 10 and the current Nvidia drivers installed as well, which are recommend for this card, so what the heck is going on here?

Any thoughts on this madness guys?

Comment: Sorry, I mean't I'm using the Claymore miner.  Any thoughts here guys?

Answer (score -1):

optimize to compute in nvidia control panel, adjust for best power performance and possibly change to an older driver.